# How to use os.path.isfile() on a list of paths

Tags: python, path, file-exists

I'm using linux8. I've got a repo (with subrepos) containing files and I have a list of the filenames (`'path/to/file/filename.pdf'`). I want to check (using python), if those files all do exist and if not, I want to know that. So I tried reading the list, iterating the list entries with a for loop and using those with `os.path.isfile()`.

E.g. I've got a repo containing following files:
list.txt,
test1.txt and
test2.txt.

The list.txt contains the filenames (here: 'test1.txt' 'test2.txt').

```
os.path.isfile('test1.txt')
```

gives a

```
True
```

But this for loop...

```
import os

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    pathlist=f.readlines()
for path in pathlist:
    print(os.path.isfile(path))
```

...gives:

```
False
False
```

although

```
type(path)
```

is

```
<type 'str'>
```

It's feels like python distinguishes two types of strings. Does anyone know, where that comes from?

Comment: Kind of. Python distinguishes strings with a new-line at the end from strings without. Try calling [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on the lines read from your file.

Comment: Try `print(repr(path))` ... `readlines` does not strip newline, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: `pathlist = map(str.strip, pathlist)` will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible problems.

First, you might not be running in the directory you believe you are.

Second, `readlines()` will return the lines with newlines and possibly carriage returns attached. You'll want to remove those before testing them as paths. You can use `rstrip()` to remove trailing whitespace from a string.

```python
for path in pathlist:
    print(os.path.isfile(path.rstrip()))
```

Comment: That worked totally fine. I thought of that, when printing the list "pathlist". But did not know, how to express the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the line of your file and check if each path exist as follow:

```
import os

with open('list.txt', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        path = line.strip()  # drop \n
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print(path)
```

Comment: That worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
os.path.isfile("/tmp") # True
```

while

```
os.path.isfile("/tmp\n") # False
```

try instead:

```
with open("/pathlist", "r") as f:
   for path in map(str.strip, f.readlines()):
       print( os.path.isfile(path))
```

Comment: This is even shorter. Nice. Works fine! Thanks!